Failing to align recursive tikz pictures to a baseline
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\partFTube[2]{% fill, total; usually integers between 0 to 10
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    [every node/.style={align=center,anchor=south},baseline=(A.base)]
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (2/5,#2/5);
    \draw[thin,SkyBlue,fill=SkyBlue] (A) rectangle ($(A-|B)!#1/#2!(B)$);
    \gettikzxy{(A)}{\Ax}{\Ay};
    \gettikzxy{(B)}{\Bx}{\By};
    \draw [thin,draw=black] (\Ax,\By) -- (A) -- (\Bx,\Ay) -- (B);
    \node () at ({(\Ax+\Bx)/2},{\By-3}) {{\small $\frac{#1}{#2}$}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand\wFTubes[6]{% 3(fill, total); usually integers between 0 to 10
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[] (A) [] at (0,0)            {};
 \node[] (B) [right=of A]           {\partFTube{#1}{#2}};
 \node[] (C) [right=of A,xshift=15] {\partFTube{#3}{#4}};
 \node[] (D) [right=of A,xshift=30] {\partFTube{#5}{#6}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \wFTubes{3}{3}{0}{5}{7}{7};
\end{tikzpicture}

This is the code. Rectangles are vertically aligned to the center-line. However, I want them to be aligned to the base-line. How can that be done?

The \wFTubes macro already contains the tikzpicture environment. You're nesting TikZ picture environments. Don't do this. Remove one environment. And remove the ; after \wFTubes. (That \partFTube also uses it and is nested in a node is not perfect but often works alright.) Please post a complete MWE.

You need to align the nodes that contains the TikZpictures, not the nested pictures themselves. If you use baseline here it just alignes the rectangles with the baseline of the nodes but you don't align the baseline of these nodes. You could add anchor=base after all other options to achieve this.

The \wFTubes macro already contains the tikzpicture environment. You're nesting TikZ picture environments. Don't do this. Remove one environment. And remove the ; after \wFTubes.
You're also putting TikZ pictures inside nodes. This is not really a good idea.
Here, the baseline option only aligns the inner TikZ pictures with the baseline of the nodes. But the nodes itself aren't aligned with the base lines. But instead, due to right=of …, their vertical centers are.
You could add anchor=base after all other options to achieve this.

However, you're making your diagram much more complicated than it is.
Code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  every tube/.style={shift=(right:#1)},
  tube/.style=draw,
  tube filled/.style={fill=SkyBlue}}
\newcommand*\wFTubesX[2][]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[y=+.5cm,#1]
  \foreach[count=\i] \a/\b in {#2}{
    \tikzset{every tube=\i}
    \path[tube filled, tube filled \i/.try]
      (0, 0) rectangle +(.75,\a);
    \path[tube, tube \i/.try]
      (0, \b) |- (right:.75) -- +(up:\b);
    \node[above] at (.375,\b) {\small $\frac{\a}{\b}$};
  }
  \end{tikzpicture}}
% for legacy reasons:
\newcommand\wFTubes[6]{\wFTubesX{#1/#2, #3/#4, #5/#6}}
\begin{document}

\wFTubes{3}{3}{0}{5}{7}{7}

\wFTubesX[
  tube filled/.style={fill=red},
  tube filled 4/.style={fill=blue}
]{1/2, 3/4, 0/7, 4/6}
\end{document}

Output

